# Leading vector taking values based on future values of another vector

Tags: r, vector, lag, lead

I have a sequence of treatments, one per day (binary), say:

`trt <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

I want to create a new vector, which corresponds to each element of `trt` and indicates whether the NEXT three treatments are all 0. For example, the indicator vector for `trt` above would be:

`indicator <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA)`

e.g. Days 3-5 have no treatment (`trt[3], trt[4], trt[5]` are all 0) so the indicator at Day 2 should equal 1 (`indicator[2]` should be 1)

There are only two requirements for `indicator`:

- 1 if the following three days will have no treatment
- 0 if the following three days will have at least one treatment
- Except it should be NA if there are <3 days left to observe

How would I do this in R? If this is doable without a for-loop, that would be ideal, but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127706/different-output-when-running-a-line-inside-vs-outside-an-ifelse-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollsum` to check whether 3 consecutive days add to zero. You'll also need to use `dplyr::lead` to account for the fact that you are looking at the *next* three days. Finally, you need to convert the resulting logical vector to numeric.

Anyway, that all boils down to this one-liner (without loops)

```r
+(dplyr::lead(zoo::rollsum(trt, 3, fill = NA, align = "left")) == 0)
#> [1]  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 NA NA NA
```

Comment: So one can use `+` to convert  `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0` ?  Is it possible to use this in a pipe? Just curious

Comment: @Ivn Ant Yes. Try  `TRUE %>% '+'` (using backticks around the "+") and you'll get 1

Comment: nice solution, simple and efficient! +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option

```
> +(rowSums(sapply(seq(3),function(k) `length<-`(trt[-(1:k)],length(trt)))==0)==3)
 [1]  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing a base-R version! Very good to know