# Different output when running a line inside vs. outside an ifelse() statement

Tags: r, if-statement, zoo

I am trying to run a simple command but no idea why the output is different when running it inside vs outside an `ifelse()` function. The function condition evaluates to `FALSE`, so the output should be the exact same.

However, when running it alone, the output is `0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1 NA` (as desired) but from the `ifelse()` function, the output is `0` (not desired).

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
del <- 2

dplyr::lead(zoo::rollsum(x, del - 1, fill = NA, align = "left")) == 0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE    NA

ifelse(del == 1, -1, dplyr::lead(zoo::rollsum(x, del - 1, fill = NA, align = "left")) == 0)
[1] FALSE
```

I would appreciate any help on why this is happening! Never seen something like this before. The outcomes of the `ifelse()` have different lengths depending on whether the condition is evaluated as true or false, but I don't see why this would cause a truncation of the longer output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be using `if`, not `ifelse`.  From `?ifelse` it says the following where `test` is the first argument of `ifelse`.

> > ‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’

In the question `test` is `del == 1` which is a logical scalar so the result will be one too.

Also `rollapply` can use `list(1:(del-1))` to refer to offsets 1, 2, ..., del-1 where positive offsets are ahead.  This seems cleaner since it direclty implements what is wanted rather than fixing it up later and it also uses fewer packages.

```
library(zoo)

del <- 2
if (del == 1) -1 else rollapply(x == 0, list(1:(del-1)), all, fill = NA)
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE    NA
```